# Can we solve the circle-ellipse with Swift?

Tags: swift

Since a certain time, I'm facing the [circle-elipse problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem), but I do feel like Swift protocols might help to solve it.

The circle-elipse problem is an issue that you'll encounter with many (if not all) object oriented programming languages, it's also called the square-rectangle problem, because a square is actually also a rectangle, we might want to write this in our code :

```
class Rectangle {
    var width:Double
    var height:Double

    init(width:Double,height:Double) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

}

class Square:Rectangle {
    var sideLength:Double

    init(sideLength:Double) {
        self.sideLength = sideLength
        super.init(width: sideLength, height: sideLength)
    }
}
```

But now, let's say that you create a square :

```
let mySquare = Square(sideLength:10)
```

The issue is that you'll also be able to modify it's length and height :

```
mySquare.width = 20
```

But it does not make any sense to do that, because now `mySquare` is 20 in width and 10 in height, so how can it still be a square ?

Trying to make Rectangle inherit from Square wouldn't solve the issue either, because then a Rectangle would have a sideLength, which does not make sense either...

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Describe your actual problem here.  Don't simply link to a problem.  What happens if the link dies?  Now the question would potentially become very confusing.

Comment: This link will not go away as it is a very basic problem with OO. But the answer is definitely too broad to be answered here. I guess that Swift still lacks the needed Design by Contract to solve the c/e problem. Though the Type-Gestapo seems to take a step in that direction.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I'm currently editing my question to make it more concrete.

Comment: @ThomasKilian So protocols won't help here ?

Comment: Honestly my times when I studied software engineering are 30 years ago. I would not stand for a good answer now. There are some smart guys here which eventually can give a good answer.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote and guess (hope) you will get an answer.

Comment: Does `Square` really need its own class distinct from `Rectangle` in the first place? A function that requires a square could still take `Rectangle` as argument and have a precondition that the rectangle must be a square.

Comment: @Arkku Why not, but it does not solve it in general, what if you want to represent number sets for example ?

Comment: Also, even if `Square` is a subclass of `Rectangle`, it would not necessarily have to follow the exact behaviour when it comes to the accessors, e.g., setting `width` might also set `height` to maintain the square invariant.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem can be solved by defining the subclass `Square` in this way:

```
class Square:Rectangle {
  var sideLength:Double {
    get { return width; }
    set(newSideLength) {
      width = newSideLength
      height = newSideLength
    }
  }

  override var width: Double {
    get {
      return super.width
    }
    set(newWidth) {
      super.width = newWidth
      super.height = newWidth
    }
  }

  override var height: Double {
    get {
      return super.height
    }
    set(newHeight) {
      super.height = newHeight
      super.width = newHeight
    }
  }

  init(sideLength:Double) {
    super.init(width: sideLength, height: sideLength)
  }
}
```

So that if you evaluate:

```
var mysquare = Square(sideLength: 10.0)
mysquare.width = 20
var x = mysquare.height
```

you will find in x the value 20.

Comment: The manual says: "You can provide a custom getter (and setter, if appropriate) to override any inherited property, regardless of whether the inherited property is implemented as a stored or computed property at source." [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID193), section "Overriding Property Getters and Setters". I tried it into the playground and it did not produced any error.

Comment: My Playground is crashing on the `mysquare.width = 20` statement.  Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: The same is true for me. The program compiles without giving any error, but it crashes when accessing properties of swift. Either my solution is wrong (but it is similar to yours and follows the manual) or there is some error in the swift runtime system. I will investigate some more.

Comment: I found the fix.  You need to change the six `self`s in `Square` to `super`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81646/discussion-between-renzo-and-vacawama).

Answer (score 0):

A square is a rectangle, yes.  But a mutable square is *not* a mutable rectangle: they behave differently, obeying different contracts.  A mutable rectangle has mutable width and height, which doesn't affect the other dimension.  A mutable square does not: change one, and the other changes as well.